# The Gaussian Integers, $\Bbb Z[i]$, is isomorphic to what familiar group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, gaussian-integers

This is part four of a four-part question on Gaussian Integers.  I got the other three fairly easily.  But now I'm asked to find a "familiar" group and show that $\Bbb Z[i]$ is isomorphic to it.  At first, I thought $|x|$ (not absolute value, but length, norm).  But that doesn't work.  It is a homomorphism but it's not one-to-one as 3+4i and 4+3i would both map to 5.  I also tried $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ but that didn't work either.
Can anyone gently steer me in the right direction?

p.s.  someone asked for the other three parts, so here they are.

[image]

Comment: What were the other three questions?

Comment: What went wrong with $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$? One thing you should realize is that $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a group only with respect to addition.

Comment: It's a ring.  And φ(ab)=φ(a)φ(b) wasn't true.  Do I only need to look at it from addition?  This is in a chapter on Rings, so I was trying both operations.
Or am I confusing homomorphism with just generic isomorphic functions like in linear algebra?

Comment: Part d) is asking for the group *of units*, not all of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$!  What units did you find in part c)?

Comment: You do see that part d) asks about the group of **units** of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. This, indeed, uses multiplication as the operation. The key to figuring that out is your answer to part c). How many units did you find? What are they?

Comment: OH!!!!!!  The group of units has 4 members, so it would be isomorphic to any Z group of modulo four.